# How to reference parent names in JSON response (with Groovy)

Tags: groovy, soapui, jsonslurper

I have the following JSON response in SoapUI

```
{
   "formatted":    {
      "line1": "14/8 QUAY STREET",
      "line2": "14/8 QUAY STREET"

   },
   "structure":    {
      "level": null      
   },
   "location":    {
      "nzX": 1758749.75300025      
   },
   "references":    {
      "aid": "A1003467096"    
   }
 }
```

I want the following as the output

formatted, structure, location and references.

I am using Json slurper but i am not able to get all the parent element names.

How do i do it using JSON slurper in groovy.

Comment: What have you tried so far? (i.e. show your attempt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the JSON is in a string `s`, consider the following which illustrates getting the top level keys:

```
import groovy.json.* 

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(s)

def parentNames = json.keySet()

parentNames.each { println it }
```

Comment: i don't wan't to assert anything. Say for example if i do json.Size(). It returns me 4 because there are 4 parent nodes(formatted, structure, location and refrences). Now i want the names of those 4 parent nodes. They can be anything and not necessarily the ones that i have mentioned in my example.

Comment: I have updated to show getting the top level keys and how to reference keys like a map. The assertion is merely an illustration.